# Did the Separatists' nations join the Rebel Alliance in episodes 4-6?

Tags: star-wars

Even though the separatist leaders were all killed by Anakin, did any of the nations themselves join the Rebels or did they all fall in line to the empire, post Revenge of the sith?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes.

Doing `comm -12` (Unix command to find out common lines between 2 files) on 2 lists of planets retrieved from:

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rebel_Alliance#Alliance_worlds (30 worlds listed)

and

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Confederacy_of_Independent_Systems#Astrography (102 worlds listed)

I got 8 (out of 102) that used to be CIS and became 8 out of 30 held by the Rebels (in other words, there was a fairly small chance that a CIS world would join the rebellion - less than 1 in 10 - but given the total # of the world in the galaxy (way above 102), having been in CIS seems like a factor likely to raise your chance of being a Rebel world - almost a third of Rebel worlds were ex-Separatist ones):

```
Dac
Dantooine
Mygeeto
New Plympto
Sullust
Thyferra
Togoria
Utapau
```

---

**UPDATE:**

As per New Disney Canon, there's an additional reason why many ex-CIS worlds may have had Rebel leanings - as well as why many didn't participate. In *Tarkin* book, we see both examples:

- Many ex-CIS worlds were severely hurt and punished by the Empire. The damage from Clone Wars was never repaired. Political repressions happened.
- Many ex-CIS worlds simply were destroyed as viable players, either as result of Clone Wars or as pos-Clone-War reprisals from the Emperor. They may have been candidates for Rebellion by inclination, but simply lacked ANY means, or even viable population.

Comment: I saw the `comm -12` and thought I had accidentally posted something meant for U&L...

Comment: Can you clarify your Yes answer a bit?  The question was multiple choice.  I think I'm following your logic in that at least some worlds joined the rebellion, but people unfamiliar with Unix might not, and it could use more detail (did most of the seperatist worlds join the rebellion, or just a few?)

Comment: @NorbyTheGeek - Done