# Are there records of Rebel usage of CIS technology?

Tags: star-wars, droids, star-wars-rebels

For as long as I can remember, the Rebel Alliance (at least in its earlier years) has resorted to appropriating abandoned CIS (Confederacy of Independent Systems) droids, mechs and especially ships shut down after the Clone Wars to support their resource-strapped military force, both in Legends and Disney canon.

**Are there any imagery and/or text records of such usage of Separatist tech?**

Comment: Does the stuff happening in "Tarkin" count?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42983/what-happened-to-the-battle-droids-after-star-wars-episode-3

Comment: @DVK I don't know what happened in Tarkin. Care to elaborate? Also, I've read a lot of readily available online material that mention the Rebellion obtaining CIS military tech. What I am looking for are examples of their usage - to date I've not read or seen a single battle fought by the Alliance where former Separatist droids, vehicles or battleships made an appearance.

Comment: Could you expand what CIS means [in this context](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/CIS), for those not familiar with the term?

Comment: CIS means the Confederacy of Independent Systems, and is the official political name for the Separatist faction prior to and during and Clone Wars. The two terms, I believe, are interchangeable.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - they had some sort of armed struggle against the Empire. The question is, does that count as "Rebels" for your purposes despite strictly speaking being well before the official Rebellion started by Mon Mothma (or at least, Ghost's company)

Comment: Lotsa people seem to be forgetting that in the first Thrawn book, Nightswan purchased stupid amounts of vulture droids and used them at the surrender of Umbara.

Answer (score 2):

**Disney Canon:**

***Lords of the Sith***

Cham Syndulla and a group of rebels on Ryloth use droid tri-fighters and vulture droids in an attack against the Empire.
(the events of LotS occur post RoTS and but prior to ANH)

**Tarkin**

As mentioned by DVK-in-exile in the question comments, a group of rebels also uses tri-fighters and vulture droids in an attack on an Imperial moon base

***Vader*** comic (part III)

While not quite rebels, a group of pirates uses CIS droidekas for security. Vader and a group of Stormtroopers encounter and dispose of the group.

Answer (score 1):

**EU/Legends canon:**

[Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Separatist_holdouts/Legends) (citing "*[Starships of the Galaxy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Starships_of_the_Galaxy_%28Saga_Edition%29)*") says:

> The Rebels managed to get their hands on Separatist war material, such as [Lucrehulk-class battleships],[Recusant-class light destroyer][,Rebel One] and [Munificent-class star frigates]. Many surviving frigates had roamed the galaxy for years, with their old crews serving as mercenaries or pirates. They modified their vessels to such an extent that many were unrecognizable from their original configuration. As such, they went well with the rag-tag look of the early Alliance Fleet

That article provides some further individual details as well.

Comment: Yes, I already know the Rebellion acquired Separatist ships - and probably any accompanying droids and weapons that are still operational. But are there any recorded instances of these war material seeing military action "in the name of the Rebel Alliance"?

Comment: @theg not in story works.

Answer (score 1):

### *Star Wars: Rebels*:

In the episode "The Last Battle," a squad of Rebels raid the [Agamar](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Agamar) Separatist base in an attempt to secure [Proton bombs](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Proton_bomb). They fail to acquire the ammunition but do take and later repurpose a [Sheathipede-class transport shuttle](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sheathipede-class_transport_shuttle), the [Phantom II](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Phantom_II).

[image: We found a new Phantom. -Kanan]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt to capture all uses of CIS technology used by rebels in a semi-detailed list.

- *Lords of the Sith* - Cham Syndulla's Free Ryloth movement uses vulture droids, droid tri-fighters, and buzz droids against the Empire, successfully taking down one Star Destroyer.
- *Tarkin* - Berch Teller's small rebel cell uses droid tri-fighters and vulture droids in an attempt to capture Wilhuff Tarkin's personal ship, the *Carrion Spike*.
- *Star Wars Rebels* - A small group from Phoenix Squadron goes to the planet Agamar and finds a small group of battle droids, led by general Kalani. The droids have two *Sheathipede*-class transport shuttles. The rebels and the droids joined forces and fought against the Empire in a single battle. Kalani and what was left of the battle droids separated from the rebels and took one of the shuttles, while the rebels took the other one.
- *Star Wars: Commander* - A group of rebels on Tatooine use AAT hover tanks to attack the Empire multiple times.
- *Aftermath* trilogy - A single enhanced battle droid, Mister Bones is used by a small group o rebels led by Norra Wexley.