# What did the general public think happened to the droid army?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, droids

[So we already know that the droid army was deactivated with a shut down command.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/42983/51226)

However, this was part of Darth Vader's very secret mission to Mustafar. Was the general public told of the shut down? If not, what did they believe happened to the droid army and ended the Clone Wars?

Comment: I don't really see any reason why the public would be kept in the dark about the shut down. Given that the separatists "surrendered", it seems pretty natural that their droid army would be shut down as a consequence of that.

Comment: No one cared, because throughout the movie franchise, Luke, Obi Wan, and the dude from Rogue One are the only people who don't treat droids like garbage.  Most people in the Galaxy Far, Far Away would assume that they'd all been smelted alive or recycled into moisture vaporators, and it wouldn't bother them at all.

Answer (score 3):

The Wookieepedia Legends page for the [Separatist Parliament](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Separatist_Parliament) seems to imply that the shutting down of the droid army by Darth Vader was done right before the Separatists decided to fully surrender, leaving no reason for the average galactic citizen to assume the deactivation wasn't done along with the CIS surrender