# What happened to the deactivated droid army?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, droids

What did the Empire do with the millions (if not billions) of deactivated battle droids after the end of the Clone Wars? *Were they melted down? Were they kept in storage?*

Any canon or Legends answer will be accepted!

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Separatist_Droid_Army#Legacy

Comment: This scene shows a small remnant of the original droid army. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnbT2sBFkgQ

Comment: Dumped them into a sea to rebuild reefs. http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3710334/amp/Million-dollar-waste-Amazing-photos-reveal-expensive-military-equipment-dumped-bottom-Pacific-Ocean-Second-World-War-expensive-bring-home.html

Comment: Jar Jar Binks took care of them. You should read his story for an ans-- hey, wait, where did Jar Jar go?

Comment: Dictators like monumental building projects, and those require raw materials.

Comment: Near-duplicate of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/42983/31936), except that this question allows Legends answers whereas the other does not appear to. Please use the Legends tag for Legends questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Partial answer

At least some of them reappear on Agamar in *[Star Wars Rebels season 3 episode 6 "The Last Battle"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Last_Battle)*.

> It appears that some of the droids avoided deactivation (the Super-Tactical-Droid commander of that unit believed that the deactivation order issued at the end of RoTS was an enemy trick, and ignored it) and carried on, as an autonomous Separatist Alliance unit.

It is not clear what happened to the droids who were deactivated.

Comment: Although you are looking in the right direction, I am asking past this point (I should have made it more clear), if there are any further references of the (possibly deactivated) droid army

Answer (score 4):

As an additional point to TimSparrow's point, after watching the [sixth episode](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Decommissioned) of [the Bad Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Bad_Batch) it was shown that:

> A significant number of inactive battle droids were melted down and disposed of in decommissioning sites. These decommissioning sites were heavily guarded due to the variety of military hardware that was present at the sites - being guarded by police droids.

It should be noted that this answer only applies to canon and not the Legends timeline.

Answer (score 0):

In what is arguably the first battle of the Clone Wars, the Gungans and Naboo come into the possession of a substantial batch of de-activated battle droids. Apparently they were melted down and used to beautify Naboo.

> **TRADE FEDERATION:** *Forced to capitulate and surrender the whole of
> their army on the ground, the Trade Federation’s neutralized battle
> droids and destroyed vehicles were melted down and repurposed for the
> civic beautification of Naboo.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Battles that Changed the Galaxy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy)</sup></sub>