# What happened to CIS droids that were "killed"?

Tags: star-wars

When CIS droids were destroyed by the clones what happened to the droids after the battle?

Comment: Melted down to make decorative Naboobian flatware

Comment: If the Republic had won, then likely they would have been taken for scrap metal, melted down and turned into other things, outside of scavengers robbing them of parts. If the CIS had won the battle, then likely they would have gathered and recycled them into new units. Don't have a source, just common-sense conjecture, hence comment instead of answer.

Comment: I recall being told that some of the droids either disregarded or didn't get the shutdown signal. Likely only a tiny fraction of their sheer numbers though.

Comment: This question is extremely related but is not quite a dupe: [What happened to the battle droids after The Revenge of the Sith?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/42983/58193) It asks what happened to the "living" droids and as far as I can tell nothing in the answers points to what happened to the "killed" ones.

Comment: After each battle or after the entire war?

Comment: just in general

Comment: @Kozaky Star Wars: Rebels, S3E06, ["The Last Battle"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Last_Battle) features a battalion of Battle Droids who decided that the Shutdown Command was most likely a trick sent by the Republic, and decided to ignore it.  (And, technically, I guess they were [correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palpatine))

Comment: After the end of the war there was no CIS so I'm not really sure what you're asking. There's a canonical confirmation of the fate of the droid army on Naboo though